# Not Able to Run H2o Function

Tags: r, rstudio, h2o

I was able to install h2o fine (in R) but get the following error when I run h2o.init()

> h2o.init()

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Error in value[3L] : 
  You have a 32-bit version of Java. H2O works best with 64-bit Java.
Please download the latest Java SE JDK 7 from the following URL:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

I updated java SE JDK version to 7 (and got the 64 bit) and am still receiving this error. Why is this?﻿

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have both 32 and 64 bit of Java and then when H2O starts, it still use 32bit Java.

First solution is to remove 32bit java so only 64bit Java is there and you are good to go.

If you have to keep both 32 and 64 bit Java then you would need to setup JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to your 64bit Java path and then start H2O. This way H2O will get 64bit Java runtime to start and you will not see the problem.

When you set JAVA_HOME make sue you set it correctly and it is pointing to 64bit Java.

Comment: How do you do this?  Can you provide steps?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to **set the environment** like this:

```
>install.packages("h2o")
>library(h2o)
>Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="E:/java/JAVA(1)") ##your own path of Java SE intalled
```

Answer (score 0):

Download and Install Java 64-bit.

Java 32-bit path will be in `C:\Program Files (x86)` and 64-bit will be in `C:\Program Files`

Change the path of JAVA_HOME to point to your 64-bit installation.

To do that, copy the installation path, navigate to your system variable, and paste the new path.
Restart your computer

[image]