# h2o init error without admin rights

Tags: h2o, rjava

I am trying for first time to use h2o package in R. My problem comes when I try to use `h2o.init()` function I have the next error message

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
You have a 32-bit version of Java. H2O works best with 64-bit Java.
Please download the latest Java SE JDK 7 from the following URL:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1]="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin/bin/java.exe": El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada
```

I have followed the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148636/not-able-to-run-h2o-function) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060916/error-when-starting-h2o-init-in-r) But I still have the same error things become worst since i do not have admin rights. Does any one can point me somewhere or give me some guide lines to get this solve?? This is driving me crazy.

My sesion info is

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
JAVA(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Can you show the error message after you've followed the first solution you linked to, i.e. after you've removed 32-bit Java. It has to be different.  (Try removing 32-bit Java, and test, before installing 64-bit Java - you should get a complaint about Java not being installed, not a complaint about Java being 32-bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your local system environment you can set the JAVA_HOME as below:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\\PATH_TO_YOUR_JAVA_1.8_INSTALL
```

After that you can check and confirm that your command line environment shows 64bit Java along with Sys.getenv call shows the 64 bit Java 1.8 as your java environment.

```
> Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
[1] "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

If it is not set in R environment then you can set it as below too:

```
> Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME= "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home")
```

Make sure to restart R/Rstudio with clean session so you have updated R with new environment. After that when you will call h2o initialize function it will pickup the right Java to get it started.

```
h2o.init()
```